# Get click position on a canvas in a handler of a context-menu

Tags: eclipse, location, coordinates, contextmenu, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP-Application, where a menu-contribution is registered, so that a context-menu will automatically be shown, when the user right-clicks on a special canvas in a defined view.

Now in some handlers I want to be able, to get the mouse coordinates, where the user clicked on the canvas, when the context-menu was shown. These handlers will be executed by commands, defined in this context-menu.

The ExecutionEvent in the execute-method of the handler doesn't provide this information.

How do I get the cursor position, the user clicked, to open the context-menu?

Answer (score 1):

If the context menu is opened via a mouse event, then `ExecutionEvent.getTrigger()` will be the SWT `MouseDown` event, which includes the correct coordinates.

Comment: even if this question is 2 years old: I have the same exact problem as the user who asked the question. I don't get any position related information with your solution. I hope someone can help me out. I've been looking for a solution for ages.

Comment: What do you get via `getTrigger()`?

Comment: no real coordinates. no matter where i open the context menu:Event {type=13 MenuItem {Copy Ctrl+C} time=3695913 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=0}

Comment: So you have activated your command via a menu item... and then your stuck. You can add a mouse listener to your canvas to get the last location where the user clicked - entertaining a sort of selected point in the canvas - but then you will also want to add some sort of visual aid to the canvas so the user can "see" the point.

Comment: Do you know any possible way to do that without a mouse listener?

Comment: I think you also get the coordinated with a button listener, but I haven't checked.

Comment: Sorry i mean without a listener at all. The ExecutionEvent.getTrigger() method seems so nice. I want to avoid to listen to an event the whole time just to get the coordinates of my context menu.

Comment: Well, you problem is that the trigger is only an SWT Event if the command is activated using the content menu of the canvas. If you go through the main menu bar, then you're stuck and need to do something else.